# Why did SQL transaction automatically rollback? Rolled back more than expected?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, ssms, sql-server-2014

I have a long SQL script I'm testing by executing it statement-by-statement in SSMS. I'm testing on a database on my local machine.

There is no "outer" transaction nor nested transactions in the script.

**Pared-down example:**

```
USE NameOfDatabase

-- rename a table (outside a transaction)
EXEC sp_rename 'Table_XYZ', 'TableZ';

-- add a column to a table (outside a transaction)
ALTER TABLE TableB
ADD NewCol {...}
```

All of these statements execute successfully, according to the output tab.

Many places in the script, I've used `BEGIN TRANSACTION`/`COMMIT TRANSACTION` with just a few statements in between. All of these have seemed to work as expected, as I've gotten the message "`Command(s) completed successfully`" when I execute the `COMMIT TRANSACTION` statement.

**Examples:**

```
-- create table statement outside a transaction
CREATE TABLE NewTableC {...}

-- inserting data from a table to be dropped, and dropping the table
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO NewTableC {...}
    SELECT {...} FROM ObsoleteTableC
    
    DROP TABLE ObsoleteTableC

COMMIT TRANSACTION    -- "Command(s) completed successfully"

-- another smaller transaction
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    -- Table HasFK_A contains the foreign key constraint 'FK_A_ToBigTable'
    DROP TABLE HasFK_A

COMMIT TRANSACTION    -- "Command(s) completed successfully"
```

Then I have one particularly large transaction in my script, where I create a new table, insert data, drop constraints, drop tables, etc.

**Example:**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    -- create replacement table with temporary name
    CREATE TABLE Tmp_BigTable {...}

    -- insert data
    INSERT INTO Tmp_BigTable {...}
    SELECT {...} FROM BigTable

    -- drop constraints to old table
    -- Table 'HasFK_A' and its constraint 'FK_A_ToBigTable' should've already been dropped in a previous transaction
    ALTER TABLE HasFK_B DROP CONSTRANT FK_B_ToBigTable
    ALTER TABLE HasFK_C DROP CONSTRANT FK_C_ToBigTable

    -- drop old table
    DROP TABLE BigTable    -- error, there are still foreign keys referencing the table

    -- rename new table
    EXEC sp_rename 'Tmp_BigTable', 'BigTable'

    -- re-add constraints
    ALTER TABLE HasFK_B DROP CONSTRANT FK_B_ToBigTable
    ALTER TABLE HasFK_C DROP CONSTRANT FK_C_ToBigTable

-- commit transaction
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

When I executed the `DROP TABLE BigTable` statement in that bigger transaction, I got an error that there was still a foreign key referencing the table.

I opened a new query window and checked `sys.foreign_keys` to see what I'd missed. Surprisingly, there were foreign keys listed from tables I had already dropped or renamed in the previous, smaller transactions that appeared to be successfully committed. I quickly wrote up the `ALTER TABLE` statements for all the remaining foreign keys, and executed those. None of them errored, which I assume meant those "dropped" and "renamed" tables were still present in the database.

I checked if the `DROP TABLE BigTable` statement would run now that I dropped the additional foreign keys. It failed again - and the remaining keys in `sys.foreign_keys` were now the ones I originally had in the script (`FK_B_ToBigTable`, `FK_C_ToBigTable`). This makes me believe the first error is when the transaction was rolled back.

I dropped those constraints and then then `BigTable`, to make sure all foreign keys had been caught. This time, `BigTable` dropped successfully. I did attempt to confirm the transaction had rolled back by renaming the new table (`Tmp_BigTable`), which did not exist, and committing the transaction, which failed because there was no open transaction.

Confusingly, it seems as if the transaction was rolled back much beyond the scope of the "big" transaction. Tables that were dropped seem to still be present, tables that were renamed seem to have their old names.

My questions are:

1. Why did the transaction automatically rollback when an error was thrown?

Per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms175523(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> If a run-time statement error (such as a constraint violation) occurs in a batch, the default behavior in the Database Engine is to roll back ***only the statement that generated the error***. You can change this behavior using the `SET XACT_ABORT` statement.

I do not have any `SET XACT_ABORT` statements in my script.

2. Why were changes rolled back (or never committed) that said "Command(s) completed successfully" when the `COMMIT` statement was executed?

---

**Edit:** I've gone through the script to find the point where the statements seem to have been rolled back to. It appears I may have accidentally forgotten to execute one of the smaller transactions' `COMMIT` statement.

So what actually got executed looked like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE ...
    EXEC sp_rename ...
    /* missed COMMIT TRANSACTION */
    
    ALTER TABLE ...
    UPDATE ...
    CREATE TABLE ...
    
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT ...
        DROP TABLE ...
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        ALTER TABLE {NewName} DROP CONSTRANT ...
        DROP TABLE ...
        
-- error on DROP TABLE rolls back both inner and outer nested transactions
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION        

SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys    -- returns foreign keys as they looked before "outer" transaction
```

So that answers question 2, but not question 1.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you referencing SQL Server 2005's documentation? Although I don't think anything has changed, you're better off reading the current version of a supported version of SQL Server.

Comment: If you don't use `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, statements can fail inside a transaction without causing a rollback and without causing the committing of that transaction to fail (not *all* statements, mind you -- just *some* statements). *Not* having `SET XACT_ABORT ON` is probably exactly what's causing your problems. See [this article series](https://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) for a much more in-depth treatment of the rather sorry state of error handling in T-SQL.

Comment: See the General Remark Section of [BEGIN TRANSACTION (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#general-remarks) too for what happens when you have an explicit transaction. *"...  or errors are encountered and **all modifications** are erased with a ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement."*

Comment: @Larnu - I followed the link to the documentation from another SO answer, and didn't think about the version.

Comment: In [Sommarskog's articles linked by @JeroenMostert](https://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#classification) most DDL errors are shown as `Batch Abortion with Rollback`

Comment: So what I quoted from MSDN "the default behavior ... is to roll back only the statement that generated the error" is not true then?

Comment: @Charlieface - thank you for that, I didn't read on to the other articles in that list. But even there, with `XACT_ABORT` `OFF`, it says that category does not roll back the transaction. Can `XACT_ABORT` be set `ON` as a default at the database or server level?

Comment: Never mind. You said they're under "Batch-aborting" (Batch Abortion with Rollback) not "Batch-only aborting" (Batch Abortion without Rollback). I misread.

Comment: [From elsewhere in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) "When SET XACT_ABORT is OFF, in some cases only the Transact-SQL statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction continues processing. Depending upon the severity of the error, the entire transaction may be rolled back even when SET XACT_ABORT is OFF."

Comment: The MSDN does not lie, as such, but neither does it tell the truth, as such. :P Unfortunately `SET XACT_ABORT ON` can't be applied as a global default, but you may as well treat it as one yourself where possible (all stored procedures I write start with `SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON` as a matter of reflex, for example). When using transactions in particular, there is very little reason to not alway use both `SET XACT_ABORT ON` and `TRY .. CATCH`, to minimize surprises and undesirable behavior.